# How to get an Excel table's Summary property from JavaScript on the client side using the Ewa namespace

Tags: web-part, javascript, sharepoint-addin, excel-services, vba

**Background:** The value of the Summary property corresponds to the setting of the Description box in the Alternative Text dialog box, which is displayed by right-clicking on an Excel table and then clicking Alternative Text.

You can get to it the property from VBA when you have a ListObject reference like so:

```
Dim mytable As ListObject
Set myTable ....
MsgBox myTable.Summary
```

From C# / .NET / VSTO:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.listobject.summary.aspx

**Question:** I want to be able to get to this property using the EWA namespace (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee589018.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

In JavaScript, let's say that I have:

```
const ewa = ewaRef.EwaControl.getInstances().getItem(0);
```

to get to an Excel Web Part.  Now I can get to the "name items" of the active workbook, of which my table will be one of:

```
const wb = ewa.getActiveWorkbook();
var namedItems = wb.getNamedItems();
const table = namedItems.getItemByName('Table1');
```

And I can validate it's an actual table:

```
    if (table.getNamedItemType() !== Ewa.NamedItemType.Table) {
        return;
    }
```

Sample Ewa code: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee660116.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

When I look at the properties of the Table object in the browser's debugger, I don't get any clues.